# Failed to initialize plugin:

Tags: joomla, tinymce

I have a Joomla website that I use tiny MCE as the text editor on. Recently I moved the website from an in house server to a hosting service via Akeeba backup. after the transfer the site works fine but when I went into the back end administration panel I found that every time I try to use the editor I get a string of failed to initialize plugin errors, every plugin imaginable. I have tried to find a fix via the Joomla forums and the hosing service's tech support but the only solution they could come up with is to start over and let them do the transfer. I'm not fond of this solution and cant help thinking that since the only problem is with the tiny MCE editor that it should be possible to reinstall this but i have no idea where to even start. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this or fix my problem any other way I would sure appreciate the help[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c3Gm.png)

I have confirmed that the webhost and my in home server are using the same version of PHP, That I see no other errors other than the plugin initialization errors, and I have another site with the same versions that I built on the hosts server that have no errors so it shouldn't be anything with their settings.